# Reg expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex, user-agent

I know what this does, but can someone explain to me the reg ex syntax in PHP for this string?

```
if (preg_match("/(?:iPhone|Android.*Mobile)/", $user_agent) > 0) {
```

I know that it finds iPhone or Android in the user-agent string, this is what I'm looking for:

```
? means what - beginning of string?
: means what - characters leading up to the search phrase?
.*Mobile means it will only match iPhone blah blah Mobile or Android blah blah Mobile?
```

One more question - do we need the " > 0" to indicate a match, or can I just do an "if" expression?

Thank you.

Comment: You're right, you don't need the `> 0` part of this test. The function returns 0 on failure or 1 on success, so just the `if` will be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(?: ... )` is a non-capturing group.

`.` is a 'wildcard' and will match any character except newlines. `*` is a quantifier and stands for 0 or more times. `.*` means any character 0 or more times.

`(?:iPhone|Android.*Mobile)` means either of `iPhone` *or* (that's what the `|` is for) `Android` and `Mobile` with any number of characters in between the two words.

In this regex, the non-capturing group is actually not required and will work even if written as:

```
if (preg_match("/iPhone|Android.*Mobile/", $user_agent) > 0) {
```

EDIT: Oh, and forgot to mention that the `> 0` part is not required either. `preg_match` already returns 0 or 1 which will be treated as boolean by the `if`.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.
What we're trying to accomplish is routing to certain pages based on version of either iOS or Android. The team that developed our search app did so about 4 years ago and it doesn't work on iOS 6 or Android 4. We were going to read the iOS/Android version and then redirect based on old/new versions. So my next step would be something like:
    if (preg_match("/iPhone IOS \d_ | Android \d.\d.*Mobile/", $user_agent) { move function }

Comment: @Tensigh Okay. `\d` matches a digit (and some other characters, but it's usually okay to use this). The regex will match something like `iPhone IOS 6_ ` or `Android 6a0 something here Mobile`. I'm not sure if the first underscore was intended, and the first dot in `\d.\d` should be escaped: `\d\.\d` (because remember `.` is a wildcard) and for future versions, I would advise for: `\d+\.\d+` (to allow 6.10, etc). Do you perhaps need more help?

Comment: Thanks, Jerry. That will be a big help. The underscore was intended - when I looked at our user-agent logs, virtually all of the iPhone logs had the format of IOS X_Y or X_Y_Z. Let me try that tomorrow and I'll post the results.

Comment: Jerry, that worked. I made the regular expression easy at first: ("/iPhone OS 6|Android 4*.Mobile/"), but I'll soon change it so it will adapt to other versions more dynamically.